# Is there a record function in Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to google scripts and I am hoping that it might be able to record and create code on my behalf by watching me perform a repetitive action once, like I am able to do in excel and VBA.

I would like the script add-on to scroll through my sheet, find all tasks defined as "completed" and then copy and paste them to another sheet titled "complete". It's a simple task but I can't seem to find any information on how to record this action and have the code created for me.

Thank you for your help!

All the best,
Elizabeth

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no record function in Apps Script environment similar to Excel. You'll have to write the script manually. Here's a [good overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't before but you can now or very soon depending where you are in the world.

Tools -> Macros -> Record Macro

APRIL 2018

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/04/think-macro-google-sheets.html